# Sort points not correct

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, opencv

I want to sort my output points with C# 
This is my visual output 
[image]

and my console output is:

- 388, 380
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 53, 211
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 53, 211
- 391, 206
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 53, 211
- 220, 211
- 391, 206
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 53, 211
- 220, 211
- 391, 206
- 220, 43
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 53, 211
- 220, 211
- 391, 206
- 220, 43
- 52, 43
- 388, 380
- 220, 379
- 53, 379
- 53, 211
- 220, 211
- 391, 206
- 220, 43
- 52, 43
- 389, 42

and here is my code:

```
PosList.Add(cog);
PosList = PosList.OrderByDescending(p=>p.Y).ToList();
```

I can't sort my points, can you please help me to create a sort ...

Comment: Well that code is not enough to understand your problem. What is cog? How is defined? Please read how to post a [mcve]

Comment: The code is too short but it should produce a list ordered by Y. Also clearly state the expected and actual outcomes.

Comment: @Steve cog is output points from contours in c#

Comment: @MazyarYousefiNia You may find reading [mcve] of value. Basically, what you should do is create a code sample (that includes populating the `List`) that we can copy and paste into a console app and run. _Be sure to specify the explicit output you are trying to generate._

Comment: You should not only compare by `Y`, but also with `X`. Result in color :https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1OWY.png

Answer (score -2):

Try following :

```
            List<Point> points = new List<Point>() {
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(53, 211),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(53, 211),
                new Point(391, 206),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(53, 211),
                new Point(220, 211),
                new Point(391, 206),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(53, 211),
                new Point(220, 211),
                new Point(391, 206),
                new Point(220, 43),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(53, 211),
                new Point(220, 211),
                new Point(391, 206),
                new Point(220, 43),
                new Point(52, 43),
                new Point(388, 380),
                new Point(220, 379),
                new Point(53, 379),
                new Point(53, 211),
                new Point(220, 211),
                new Point(391, 206),
                new Point(220, 43),
                new Point(52, 43),
                new Point(389, 42)
            };


            List<List<Point>> sorted = points.OrderBy(x => x.Y).ThenBy(x => x.X).GroupBy(x => x.Y).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```